# OSX - QR code encoder for Objective-C not compiling

Tags: ios, macos

I have compiled this library for iOS projects many times. However now i want this in a Mac OSX application, and i get the following error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/vrzolt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ORCoffeeRoastersLoyaltyCardUserGenerator-elbondminwnjeugejppzsblnalqr/Build/Products/Debug/libqrencoder.a'

I use the documentation from here: https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C

Do i need to change something in the settings to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Zoli

Comment: And have you configured the project to build that library under OSX?

Comment: I just did. Now the project's missing the UIKit framework that is for iOS. Can i add it to an OSX app?

Comment: You need separate iOS and OSX targets, each with different build settings and dependant frameworks.  You will probably have to override the "output file name" (or whatever its called) setting as Xcode likes to use the name of the target by default.

Comment: That's what i did. the qr code encoder is a subproject and has ios as a target, the main project is left osx. Then i get the error i presented above

Comment: Sounds like the dependencies haven't been set so Xcode is not compiling the library.

Comment: True. I set it up to work, now it conflicts with an other library i use. Oh my :)

Comment: Ah, maybe you do have to give the output libraries different names.  This rings a bell.

Comment: finally modifying the library brought me success for a while. Now i'm facing another issue with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003794/osx-project-with-an-ios-project-embedded-uikit-h-not-found