# OSX project with an iOS project embedded - UIKit.h not found

Tags: ios, macos

I have an OSX project with an iOS subproject. The subproject uses UIKit.h, but even though the subproject has the UIKit framework added to the Link Binary with Libraries section, i still get the error saying:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue error UIKit/UIKit.h file not found

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just need some conditional compilation:

I have a project that builds for both OSX and iOS that shares source code.  I have a header file called `SysInfo.h` that has this at the top:

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define SYSINFO_OSX 1
#else
#define SYSINFO_IOS 1
#endif
```

(as well as other stuff that isn't relevant here)

and can then use it like this:

```
#import "SysInfo.h"

#ifdef SYSINFO_OSX
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#else // !SYSINFO_OSX
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif // SYSINFO_OSX
```

Of course, this is just the tip of the iceberg as you will need to ensure you use the correct APIs on the correct platform, using much the same approach.

Comment: macro black magic. Thank you :)